# Send JSON with Alt-text to CKEditor Image Plugin

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor, liferay

I want to send a JSON with 'url' and 'alt' to the client and i want the ckeditor (version 4) to support those values.

I have a Server Side Java Class that sends a JSON to the client. It contains 'url' and 'alt' from an Image on my Server.

On the client side I'm using CKEditors Enahnced Image Plugin. It picks up the url automatically, but the alt text is not being recognized. I tried to find the spot in the JavaScript where the Editor reads the JSON but I could not find it.

Im Using Liferays JSONFactoryUtil to build the JSON string

```java
    JSONObject fileEntryJSONObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    fileEntryJSONObject.put("url", previewURL);
    fileEntryJSONObject.put("alt", getMetadataAltText(fileEntry, themeDisplay));

    return fileEntryJSONObject.toString();
```

Is there some keyword CKEditor is looking for, inside the JSON i can use for the alt text? If not, how can I manipulate the Ckeditor to be able to read my json properly?

Comment: See if this helps: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_imagetextalternative-ImageTextAlternative.html. Not sure but require an image plugin ?

Comment: Should have included that in the question earlier: Im using ckeditor 4. But thanks, i will have a deeper look in the Docu (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/index.html - if anyone reading needs this)